# Java - Return an array from array with two given indexes

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Let's say I have an array:

```
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 0};
```

With two indexes (let's say `2` and `5`), I want to be able to return array from indexes `2` to `5` from the variable `values` given above. The final output should be this:

```
newValues[] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Also, how would this procedure be used with multi dimensional arrays?

I would have googled this, but I'm not sure what to google, so I came here.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#subarray(java.lang.Object[], int, int)

Comment: `Arrays.copyOfRange(original, from, to)` `to` index is excluded in result array so you will have to correct it with +1.

Answer (score 10):

Use `java.util Arrays` class. Use `copyOfRange(int[] original, int from, int to)` method:

```
newValues[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(values, 2, 6);
```

Comment: While this is working fine for single-dimensional Arrays, this does not answer the multidimensional part of the question.

Comment: I agree. But, each multidimensional array can be converted to 1D array and transformed with this function.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

    int start = 2, end = 5; // Index
    int[] newValues = new int[end - start + 1]; // Create new array

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        newValues[i - start] = values[i]; // Assign values
    }

    // Print newValues
    for (int v : newValues) {
        System.out.print(v + " ");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3 4 5 6
```

Comment: wat abt multi-dimenstion array?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following for 2D arrays:

```
public int[][] getRange(int[][] src, int x, int y, int x2, int y2) {
    int[][] ret = new int[x2-x+1][y2-y+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= x2-x; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <= y2-y; j++)
            ret[i][j] = src[x+i][y+j];
    return ret;
}
```

For 1D Arrays, `Arrays.copyOfRange()` should be fine and for more dimensions you can simply add more params and `for` loops

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for. I would mark this right, but I'm looking for something more "built in". Do you know if there is something equivalent to `Arrays.copyOfRange()` for multi-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

`int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 0};
     int newValues[] = new int[4];
     System.arraycopy(values,1,newValues,0,4)`

Here's the complete code :

```
public class CopyRange {    
  public static void main (String...args){
     int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 0};
     int newValues[] = new int[4];

     System.arraycopy(values,1,newValues,0,4);

     for (int i =0;i <newValues.length;i++)
        System.out.print(newValues[i] + " ");
     }
}
```

The System class has an arraycopy method that you can use to efficiently copy data from one array into another:

public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)